# sceneUpdated() vs invalidate()

Tags: autodesk-forge

What is the difference between `viewer.impl.sceneUpdated()` and `viewer.impl.invalidate()`? I’ve seen them used interchangeably all the time but haven’t been able to figure out why.

In the case of `invalidate()`, I have seen it used accepting 1 to 3 boolean arguments with every possible combination and it seems to give the same result every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewer.impl.invalidate` is basically:

```
invalidate(needsClear, needsRender, overlayDirty)
//needsClear - full render - not (currently) interruptible, runs until completion, "locks" application, needs to re-render the whole scene from start
//needRender - progressive render - show a bit more each tick, runs unless interrupted by a move, control, etc.
//overlayDirty - overlay (like rollover highlighting etc) needs to be re-rendered
```

And `sceneUpdated(objectsMoved, skipRepaint)` is basically

```
this.invalidate(!skipRepaint, false, !skipRepaint);
```

Plus the scene bounds are getting remarked for update and the shadows'd get re-rendered.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't have asked for a better answer.